# How to initialize passport (issue with exporting)

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have some issues to initiate passport.

- I call the function app.use(passport.initialize()); in the file server.js
- In the file auth.controllers.js passport is not detected as initialized

Somebody could explain how to "connect" app.use(passport.initialize()) in the server.js to the file auth.controllers.js ?

here my files :

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const networkConfig = require("./config/network.config");

const app = express();

const db = require("./config/models");
db.sequelize.sync();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: networkConfig.corsOptions.ORIGIN
};

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(morgan('combined'));

// parsing sur les requetes en type json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parsing des urls encodés
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// route de vérification de bon fonctionnement
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: "Bienvenue ici"});
});


require("./routes/user.routes")(app);
require("./routes/oauth2.route")(app);
require("./routes/client.routes")(app);
require("./routes/beer.routes")(app);

const ejs = require('ejs');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

/*
const beerController = require('./controllers/beer');
const userController = require('./controllers/user');
const authController = require('./controllers/auth');
const oauth2Controller = require('./controllers/oauth2');
const clientController = require('./controllers/client');
*/

// Set view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use express session support since OAuth2orize requires it
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Super Secret Session Key',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Use the passport package in our application
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Start the server
app.listen(3000);
```

user.routes.js

```
module.exports = app => {
    
const users = require("../controllers/user.controllers");
const auths = require("../controllers/auth.controllers")(app);

const router = require("express").Router();


// Create endpoint handlers for /users
router.route('/')
  .post(users.create)
  .get(auths.isAuthenticated, users.findAll);

app.use('/api/users', router);
};
```

auth.controllers.js

```
// Load required packages
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy
const db = require("../config/models");
const User = db.user;
const Client = db.client;
const Token = db.token;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

passport.use(new BasicStrategy( (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
      .then(function (data) {
        if (!data) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'user does not exist'});
        } else {
          var verify = data.verifyPassword(password);
          if(verify == true) { console.log("verify true"); return done(null, data, {message: 'authentication succeded'})}
        }           
      })
      .catch( (err) => {
        console.log("Error reason : "+ err);
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Something went wrong with you authentication'});
        }
      )
  }
));

passport.use('client-basic', new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, callback) {
    console.log("CLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASICCLIENT-BASIC");
    Client.findOne({ id: username }, function (err, client) {
      if (err) { return callback(err); }

      // No client found with that id or bad password
      if (!client || client.secret !== password) { return callback(null, false); }

      // Success
      return callback(null, client);
    });
  }
));
exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('basic', { session : false });
exports.isClientAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('client-basic', { session : false });
```

How could I resolve this problem ?

Regards,

Comment: please, check this example. You should define passport before routes: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js

Comment: @SergeyReus it was so obvious. Thanks a lot for your help !